# international character problem

Tags: php, utf-8, gettext

even though php page's header set to UTF-8 i get this error

[image: error]

here is meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

text is coming from php gettext.

how can i solve this ?

thanks

Comment: The same thing happens to me all the time, but I just end up getting lazy and using win-1252 encoding.

Comment: What encoding is the file containing that string saved in. @Kevin Verbal reprimand for laziness. >:-P

Comment: Is this error in your broswer?  If so, which platform(s)/browser(s)?  Where is this error?  Can you go to the browser's developer mode and examine the http headers for us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output is probably encoded in ISO-8859-1 when it came from gettext. While you could manually convert it with `utf8_encode()`, there is a builtin feature for gettext which should do that automatically.

See the user comment here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bind-textdomain-codeset.php#67200

In your case you would need:

```
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, "UTF-8");
```

Obviously it would be best if your gettext .mo files were encoded in UTF-8 too.

If that doesn't help yet, try overriding the locale with `setlocale("de_DE.UTF-8")` or maybe `putenv("LC_MESSAGES", "de_DE.UTF-8")` and `LANG=` or similar.